# Trying to sort string given with respective order, cannot use collection

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm having trouble to sort String in my linkedList, number i can easily compare to each other and make them ascending order or descending.

```
public class Node
{
    private Shape shape; 
    private Node nextNode;
    private Node PreviousNode;
    private boolean front = false;

    Node() 
    {
       this.shape = null;
       this.nextNode = null;
       this.previousNode = null;
    }

    public Node(Shape shape, Node active)
    {
        this.shape = shape;
        this.nextNode = null;
        this.previousNode = null;
    }

    public Node addNode(Shape shape)
    getShape()
    setShape(Shape shape)
    getNextNode()
    setNextNode(Node nextNode)
    getPreviousNode()
    setPreviousNode(Node previousNode)
    public boolean front()
    public void setFront(boolean front)
}
```

---

The order should be like this (Square,rectangle,circle,oval,line)

```
   public class linkedlist
   {
      Node front
      Node end



   public linkedlist()
   {
      this.setFront(null);
      this.end = null;
   }

   public void addFront(Shape shape)
   public void addNewNode(Shape shape)

   public boolean AscendingOrder(Node current)
   {
      Node compareNextNode = current.getNextNode();
      while(!compareNextNode.equals(null))
      {
         if(current.getShape().TypeOfShape == "SQUARE")
         {
             Node PreviousCurrent = current.getNextNode();
```

Then I have no idea how to build the algorithm to sort the rest of the shape
If anyone have any good reference that can help me, i'll be glad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this:

1. Make your `Shape` class implements `Comparable<Shape>`.
2. Define a `final static String[] shapeOrder;` array which defines the order of the shapes.
3. Implement the `compareTo` method using this previous array: first get the index of the current shape based on the `shapeOrder` array and `TypeOfShape`. After getting the index for both the current object and the object to compare with, compare the indexes, the lesser index will be the *minor*, the greater index will be the *major* (this behavior will depend on your usage).
4. In your sorting algorithm, when doing the comparison, just do `current.getShape().compareTo(otherNode.getShape())`, and use the returned value (less than 0, 0, greater than 0) to do the sorting.

If you want to do both ascending and descending order, create two classes that implement `Comparator<Shape>` instead, with a similar comparison logic as described above.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create an `enum` for your shape types, like this:

```
enum ShapeType {
    SQUARE,
    RECTANGLE,
    CIRCLE,
    OVAL,
    LINE
}
```

Then declare `Shape.TypeOfShape` to be of type `ShapeType` instead of `String`. The elements of an enum are comparable, for example:

```
if (ShapeType.SQUARE.compareTo (ShapeType.CIRCLE) < 0)
```

would evaluate to true. So you could do this to compare two shape nodes:

```
if (current.getShape().TypeOfShape.compareTo (compareNextNode.getShape().TypeOfShape) < 0)
```

To see if the current shape is "less" than the shape of `compareNextNode`.